# How to get adb remount to work?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm attempting to remove certain files from the SD image mounted on the emulator.

```
NDUNN-PC ~
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device


NDUNN-PC ~
$ adb shell rm -f /sdcard/maps/*
rm failed for -f, Read-only file system

NDUNN-PC ~
$ adb remount
remount succeeded

NDUNN-PC ~
$ adb shell rm -f /sdcard/maps/*
rm failed for -f, Read-only file system
```

From all the docs I've read, remount is supposed to toggle between read-write/read-only permissions.  But that doesn't seem to work in this case.  Any idea what's wrong?  Using Windows XP, emulator is running Android SDK 1.6 (with Google Maps APIs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the -f command from rm made it work.  Weird.

Comment: because -f is not a supported option and is considered a file by 'rm'.